# Chained selectors not correct in querySelector

Tags: javascript

I'm not understanding why my chain of `querySelector` is invalid. I'm converting these from jQuery, but from what I'm reading this is totally doable.

This is my incorrect code...

```
document.querySelector(":button[name='checkout'], a[href$='checkout'], form[action='/cart'], input[name='checkout']").addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log("do something")
})
```

It errors with:

> Uncaught DOMException: Document.querySelector: ':button[name='checkout'], a[href$='checkout'], form[action='/cart'], input[name='checkout']' is not a valid selector

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why the `:` in front of `button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`:button` is a jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/button-selector/), not a standard CSS selector. You'll need to replace that with CSS. The jQuery documentation says:

> An equivalent selector to `$( ":button" )` using valid CSS is `$( "button, input[type='button']" )`.

So you can use `button[name='checkout'], input[type='button'][name='checkout']` (and probably omit one of those based on your actual HTML).